# How to pass events from ViewModel to Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to go to MainScreen after receive for server response in SplashViewModel.

I have in a compose to listen to ViewModel's events.

Are there any potential problems with this method?

Or is there any other method recommended by Android?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    viewModel: SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateToMain: () -> Unit,
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    LaunchedEffect(viewModel, lifecycleOwner) {
        viewModel.event.collect {
            when (it) {
                SplashEvent.INITIALIZED -> {
                    navigateToMain()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of what type of flow `event` is, there might be some problems. If it's a `SharedFlow`, you might miss some events in situations when event is emited and the UI is not collecting yet - for example, you can emit while user is rotating screen when the old UI is already destroyed and unsubscribed and new UI not yet subscribed.

On the other hand, if it's a `StateFlow`, you won't miss any event, but you can receive one event multiple times - when you navigate back from `main`, the initial event will still be there and you will go immediately back to `main`.

Current recommendation from the Android team is having the events part of your uiState (`StateFlow`) and consume them from UI. See https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events#handle-viewmodel-events.